# update specific column of a row in mysql after every 5 minutes unsing node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am working on a project with node.js (not express) server and a mysql database. When a user clicks a button on the page, it uploads 2 values (say SpecificName, Yes/No). Now these values get inserted into the mysql database through the node server. Later, mysql runs a check for the specificName column (if it finds none, it then creates a column with the same Name) and updates the second value in it.

Now I would like to keep every update of the second value that the user makes through website (i.e yes) for 5 minutes in the mysql database after which it automatically updates the the specific location with another value (say cancel). I'm auspicious in solving every thing except this 5 minutes paradox. Also I'm keeping 15-20 so called specificName columns in which the value (say yes/no) is being updated and at the same time there are more than 1000 rows that are working simultaneously so a lots of 5 minute timers going on for the values. Is there a way to store value temporarily in mysql after which it is destroyed automatically?.

I came across :

1. node-crons (too complex, don't even know if its a right choice)
2. mysql events (I'm not sure how to use it with node)
3. timestamp (can't create more than one timestamp (guess I need one for each column))
4. datetime (haven't tested it yet) and other things like
   (DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `timestamp` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)).
   Now I have no idea what to use or how to resolve this dilemma.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Per my conversation with Sammy on kik, **I'm pretty sure you don't want to do this.** This doesn't sound like a use case that fits MySQL. I also worry that your MySQL knowledge is super limited, in which case, **you should take the time to do more research on MySQL**. Without a better understanding of the larger goal(s) your application is trying to accomplish, I can't suggest better alternatives. If you can think of a way to explain the application behavior without compromising the product idea, that would be very helpful in helping us solve your problem.

General things I want to make clear before giving you potential answers:

- **You should not be altering columns from your application.** This is one of my issues with the Node/Mongo world. Relational databases don't like frequently changing table definitions. It's a quick way to a painful day. Doing so is fine in non-relational systems like Mongo or Cassandra, but traditional relational databases do not like this. The application should only be inserting, updating, and deleting rows. Ye hath been warned.
- I'm not sure you want to put data into MySQL that has a short expiration date. You probably want some sort of caching solution like [memcache](http://memcached.org/) or [redis](http://redis.io/). Now, you can make MySQL behave like a cache, but this is not its intended use. There are better solutions. If you're persistent on using MySQL for this, I recommend investigating the [MEMORY storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/memory-storage-engine.html) for faster reads/writes at the cost of losing data if the system suddenly shuts down.

Here are some potential solutions:

- [MySQL Events](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html) - Have a timestamp column and an event scheduled to run... say every minute or so. If the event finds that a row has lived more than 5 minutes, delete it.
- [NodeJS setTimeout](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.1/api/timers.html) - From the application, after inserting the record(s), set a timeout for 5 minutes to go and delete said records. You'll probably want to ensure you have some sort of id or timestamp column for supahfast reference of the values.

Those are the two best solutions that come to mind for me. Again, if you're comfortable revealing how your application behaves that requires an unusual solution like this, we can likely help you arrive at a better solution.

Comment: Sammy brought up performance concerns about doing a setTimeout on the web server for 5 minutes. This is an entirely valid concern. You would want to test.

Comment: Ok thank you for the concerns I hv given the hold to Sammy. You may ask him whatever you feel relevant.

Comment: instead of halting node app using timeout function i prefer to use node cron to execute a function and stop the cron when some conditions meet

Comment: I dont have any problems in using crons but is it possible to manage so many rows of mysql where the data is feeded inside lot of columns per user only for 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

ok so guess i figured it out myself. I'm posting this answer for all those who still deal with this query.I used DATETIME stamp in mysql that i created for each column of specificName.so with every specificName column,there exist another specificName_TIME column that stores the time at which the value (yes/no) is updated.the reason i didn't use timestamp is because its not possible to create end number of timestamp in mysql versions lower than 5.6.Now i updated the current time by adding 5 minutes before storing it in database.Then i ran 2 chain functions. First one checks if the datetime in the database is smaller than the current time (SELECT specificName FROM TABLE WHERE specificName_TIME < NOW()).If it turns out to be true it shows me the value else it reflects null.Then i ran the second function to update the value if its true to continue the whole process again and if not to continue it anyways updating the last value with null.
HOPE THIS HELPS.